# Table cell gradient fill issue

Tags: html, css, html-table, render, gradient

When use gradient fill for table cell, I expect rendering issues with cell borders on window resize and it's not observable when solid color fill is used.

Here is one table, some cells use gradient fill, others - solid color:

[image: cell fill rendering issue]

This dark gap is visible only on particular window sizes, not always.

- Is it known issue?
- Is there any hack for this?

**Update:**

Here is an example: https://codepen.io/zur4ik/pen/bmjLVp

Try change view and resize in horizontal axes

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #140B0A;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.com-container {
  width: 1540px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fx {
  display: flex;
}
.fx.vc {
  align-items: center;
}

.com-game-table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.com-game-table thead tr th {
  background-color: #784B3E;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.com-game-table thead tr th:hover {
  background-color: #71473b;
}
.com-game-table thead tr th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.com-game-table thead tr th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr td {
  height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0 transparent;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr td .status-cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr td .status-cell .icon {
  background-image: url("../img/tb-row-play-btn-icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 10px top 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr td.col-highlight {
  background: #eeeeee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
}
.com-game-table tbody tr.started td {
  background: #30211F;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30211F 0%, #241715 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30211F 0%, #241715 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30211F 0%, #241715 100%);
  color: #989291;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr.started td .com-icon {
  opacity: .5;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr.started td .com-icon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr.started td .status-cell .icon {
  background-image: url("../img/tb-row-view-btn-icon.png");
  background-position: left 6px top 50%;
  opacity: .7;
}
.com-game-table tbody tr.started td.col-highlight {
  background: #2a1d1b;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2a1d1b 0%, #1e1311 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2a1d1b 0%, #1e1311 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2a1d1b 0%, #1e1311 100%);
}
.com-game-table tbody tr:hover td {
  background: white;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
}
.com-game-table tbody tr:hover.started td {
  background: #332321;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #332321 0%, #271917 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #332321 0%, #271917 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #332321 0%, #271917 100%);
}
.com-game-table tbody tr:hover.started td .status-cell .icon {
  opacity: .8;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-1"] {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-2"] {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-3"] {
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-4"] {
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-5"] {
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-6"] {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-7"] {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-8"] {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: right;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
main .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  min-height: 0;
}
main .content .content-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-header {
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-header:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #140B0A;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-header .com-game-table {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body .table-body-inner {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body .com-game-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body .com-game-table tbody tr td .com-icon.tooltip {
  cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="com-container fx">
      <div class="content-body">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
          <div class="table-header">
            <table class="com-game-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-1">A</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-2">B</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-3">C</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-4">D</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-5">E</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-6">F</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-7">G</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="table-body">
            <div class="table-body-inner">
              <table class="com-game-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: I am pretty sure it's an optical illusion

Comment: Your example does not seem to suffer the issue you are stating. In what browser is the issue present? Also why are you using tables if your using flex? Use tables or grid.

Comment: @DreamTeK This is just part code of whole project and that's why it looks crazy. Other part of code is not presented here. I use Chrome. Try to resize window in horizontal axes and you'll see vertical lines between columns.

Comment: @zur4ik OK. I only see the issue in Edge, is this your experience?

Comment: @DreamTeK did you tried to play with window width? I expect this issue in Chrome, Firefox and Edge too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from what I can work out, this is a sub-pixel rounding problem in Chrome and Edge. 
A linear gradient behaves like a background image and is tessellated across the background.

I am not clear on the precise behaviour of the rendering engine but when certain widths are not divisible a 1px gap is introduced.

Firefox doesn't appear to suffer this issue because I suspect it rounds up.

---

**WORKAROUND**

We cannot get rid of the gap created in Chrome but we can hide the fact from the end user.

- Apply the gradient to the row instead of the cell. The cell needs to remain transparent.
- Apply no-repeat so the background gradient doesn't try to tile incorrectly.

**CSS**

```
.com-game-table tbody tr {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

**EXAMPLE**

In the example below I have applied the following fix to **ONLY** the white rows.

It will need appling to rows of alternate colors and also to hover effects.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #140B0A;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.com-container {
  width: 1540px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fx {
  display: flex;
}

.fx.vc {
  align-items: center;
}

.com-game-table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.com-game-table thead tr th {
  background-color: #784B3E;
  height: 60px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.com-game-table thead tr th:hover {
  background-color: #71473b;
}

.com-game-table thead tr th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.com-game-table thead tr th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FBFBFB 0%, #EFEFEF 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr td {
  height: 60px;
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0 transparent;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr td .status-cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr td .status-cell .icon {
  background-image: url("../img/tb-row-play-btn-icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left 10px top 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr td.col-highlight {
  background: #eeeeee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee 0%, #e2e2e2 100%);
}

.com-game-table tbody tr.started td {
  background: #30211F;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #30211F 0%, #241715 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #30211F 0%, #241715 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #30211F 0%, #241715 100%);
  color: #989291;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr.started td .com-icon {
  opacity: .5;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr.started td .com-icon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr.started td .status-cell .icon {
  background-image: url("../img/tb-row-view-btn-icon.png");
  background-position: left 6px top 50%;
  opacity: .7;
}

.com-game-table tbody tr.started td.col-highlight {
  background: #2a1d1b;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2a1d1b 0%, #1e1311 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2a1d1b 0%, #1e1311 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2a1d1b 0%, #1e1311 100%);
}

.com-game-table tbody tr:hover td {
  background: white;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, #fcfcfc 100%);
}

.com-game-table tbody tr:hover.started td {
  background: #332321;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #332321 0%, #271917 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #332321 0%, #271917 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #332321 0%, #271917 100%);
}

.com-game-table tbody tr:hover.started td .status-cell .icon {
  opacity: .8;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-1"] {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-2"] {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-3"] {
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-4"] {
  width: 130px;
  text-align: center;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-5"] {
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-6"] {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-7"] {
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.com-game-table [data-type="tb-col-8"] {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: right;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

main .content {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  min-height: 0;
}

main .content .content-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-header {
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-header:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #140B0A;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-header .com-game-table {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body .table-body-inner {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body .com-game-table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

main .content .content-body .table-wrapper .table-body .com-game-table tbody tr td .com-icon.tooltip {
  cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="com-container fx">
      <div class="content-body">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
          <div class="table-header">
            <table class="com-game-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-1">A</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-2">B</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-3">C</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-4">D</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-5">E</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-6">F</th>
                  <th data-type="tb-col-7">G</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="table-body">
            <div class="table-body-inner">
              <table class="com-game-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="free">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">2</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="started">
                    <td data-type="tb-col-1">1</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-2">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-3">3</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-4">4</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-5">5</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-6">6</td>
                    <td data-type="tb-col-7">7</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```